# Prove the set [a, b] is perfect

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, metric-spaces

How can I prove (by definition) that, if $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$, then $[a, b]$ is equal to the set of accumulation (limit) points?

Let $(E, d)$ a metric space and $S \subseteq E$. 
$x \in E$ is a limit point if $(B_\varepsilon(x)-\lbrace x \rbrace ) \cap S \neq \emptyset$ for all $\varepsilon >0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x \in [a,b]$, the $x \in B_\varepsilon(x) \cap [a,b]$ for all $\varepsilon >0$. If $x \notin [a,b]$ take $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}\min\{d(a,x),d(b,x)\}$, and notice that $B_\varepsilon(x) \cap [a,b] = \varnothing$, so $x$ is *not* a limit point of the set.

Comment: I'm confused. It's necessary to prove $x \in (B_\varepsilon(x)-\lbrace x \rbrace) \cap [a,b]$ but you only prove $x \in B_\varepsilon(x) \cap [a,b]$.

Comment: @DannyAlzate It depends on your definition of limit point, I suppose.

Comment: What you prove is my definition of adherent point, but not limit point. How can I do the proof with my definition of limit point?

Comment: @DannyAlzate I've never heard of an adherent point. It's helpful to include these details in your post.

Comment: all that needs to be changed is to observe that if $r = \min\{\epsilon,d(x,a),d(x,b)\}$ and $x \in [a,b]$, then obviously $x + \frac{r}{2}$ fits the requirements unless $x = a$ or $x = b$, in which case change $r$ by removing the distance that is zero.

Comment: @MikePierce Thanks for your recommendation. I have added the definition of limit point to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt:

$U:= ${$x| x <a$};  $V:=${$x|x >b$};

$U,V$ are open sets,

1) $U \cup V$ is open.

$[a,b]=(U \cup V)^c$ is closed ($c$ for complement in $\mathbb{R}$).

2) Let $x_0 \not \in [a,b]$, then

$x_0 \in [a,b]^c= U \cup V$, which is an open set.

Hence

$B_\epsilon (x_0) \subset U \cup V$ for an $ \epsilon >0$.

$x_0$ is not a limit point of $[a,b]$.